# Can't create blank Android Xamarin app in VS 2015

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.ios

When i try to create a blank Android project in Visual Studio 2015[image: Create new project] i get error:

[image: Object reference not set]

Desktop windows 7 Enterprise [image]
I have installed the latest versions of VS2015 and Xamarin.[image]

Comment: I know it's trivial but, did you try to restart windows ?

Answer (score 0):

Someone resolved problem on other forum - check this out.

1. Make sure Android Studio is not installed on your computer. If it is, uninstall it and run the VS2015 installer again until all Android SDK errors go away.
2. Make sure VS2015 is closed and install the most recent stable version of Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015. I found it here: https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads. (Trying to install it through VS2015 didn't work for me under Tools -> Android -> Settings -> Xamarin for Visual Studio Updates.)
3. Make sure you have Java SDK version 7 installed on your machine (do not use 8 even though its the latest). You also must use the 32-bit version even if you have a 64-bit machine. This was key!
4. Install the Android SDK. Standalone version, not Android Studio + Android SDK.
5. Install the Android NDK.
6. Restart your computer and open VS2015. Go to Tools -> Android -> Settings and set the correct paths to Android SDK, NDK and Java SDK.

Comment: Well that's great. What if I want to develop with Android Studio in parallel? Can I reinstall it afterwords?